# Webpage loses functionality on Safari but is fine on Chrome

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-website

Can someone help me understand why certain things aren't working on safari but do on chrome?

These are apparent on both mobile and desktop.

So here is the website I'm currently working on: http://stage.coefficientlabs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Problems: 
1. The hero video plays smoothly on Chrome but not on Safari. 
2. (main issue) Once the "Get Started" button is clicked, a modal appears. All the styling and content seemingly hidden(?) on Safari but not on Chrome.

Any idea what is going on here?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducible examplehttps://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: What do you use to play the video?

Comment: Have you tried to mute the video? Safari doesn't allow autoplay unless the video is muted

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was "overflow: hidden". I think is a known difference for Safari in general.